# How to split a Date vector into k columns?

Tags: r, date, matrix, vector

I have a vector with dates, e.g.

```
library("lubridate")
vec <- seq(ymd('1990-01-01'),ymd('1993-01-01'), by = '1 year')
```

which I want to split up in k columns. Assuming k= 2, the resulting data frame is supposed to look like this:

```
          X1         X2
1 1990-01-01 1992-01-01
2 1991-01-01 1993-01-01
```

The first idea could be something like this:

```
m <- matrix(vec, ncol= 2)
```

I am awere of the fact that this approach is not valid since matrix() kills the class of dates:

```
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 7305 8035
[2,] 7670 8401
```

Unfortunately, data.frame() doesn't have a ncol argument and using the matrix() function inside of data.frame() leads to the problem shown above. I couldn't find any solution to this seemingly simple question and I would be happy about help.

Comment: Do you want the dates in your columns in-sequence (like your example), or random, or do you not have a preference?

Comment: I would like to have the dates in sequence like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split into list and convert that to a `data.frame`:

```
k <- 2
df <- as.data.frame(split(vec, f = as.factor(rep(1:k, each = length(vec)/k))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Dates are internally stored as numbers, so you can convert them back after having them in the desired format.

```
k <- 2
df <- data.frame(matrix(vec, ncol = k))
df[] <- lapply(df, as.Date, origin = "1970-01-01")

df
#          X1         X2
#1 1990-01-01 1992-01-01
#2 1991-01-01 1993-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you! I prefer the solution of sindri_baldur and this is why: in my question I generated vec with seq(..) becauae it was convenient. But in fact, my vector is something like vec <- rep(dmy_hms("01/01/2000 10:11:08"), 6). Applying your solution to my actual vector gave me wrong values. The solution of sindri_baldur doesn't need any specification about the class which is an advantage and indeed, his solution worked out for me.

Comment: @igoR87 definitely, it will not give you the expected output if you are applying `as.Date` to `POSIXct` class. I used `as.Date` because you had shown dates in your input. For this new vector you need to use `as.POSIXct`, like `df[] <- lapply(df, as.POSIXct, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")` Nonetheless, sindri_baldur has got a good answer.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake and I notices it when I tried your code. I wanted to mention why I marked the answer from sindri_baldur - baucause it appears to be more general.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just 4 elements, then do

```
library(tibble)
tibble(X1 = vec[1:2], X2 = vec[3:4])
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  X1         X2        
#   <date>     <date>    
#1 1990-01-01 1992-01-01
#2 1991-01-01 1993-01-01
```

---

As a general case,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
k <- 2
tibble(X1 = vec) %>%
   group_by(grp = paste0("X", as.integer(gl(n(), k, n())))) %>%
   mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%  
   spread(grp, X1) %>%        
   select(-ind)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  X1         X2        
#  <date>     <date>    
#1 1990-01-01 1992-01-01
#2 1991-01-01 1993-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate what the middle is and then create two sequences of dates.

```
library("lubridate")

StartDate <- ymd('1990-01-01')
EndDate <- ymd('1993-01-01')
MidDate <- StartDate + years(length(seq(StartDate,EndDate, by = '1 year'))/2)
data.frame(X1 = seq(StartDate, MidDate - years(1), by = '1 year'),
           X2 = seq(MidDate, EndDate, by = '1 year') )
```

Comment: So if k changes to 3, I would have to type manually something like data.frame(X1 = seq(...), X2 = seq(...), X3= seq(...))?